# android pending intent garbage collection

Tags: android, garbage-collection, android-pendingintent

I have some repeating pending intents in my android application that I want to stay alive for as long as the phone is turned on...the problem is that the app that creates these pending intents gets unloaded from memory either because of Android OS garbage collection or from a task killer...

Is there any way to stop pending intents from being unloaded by the garbage collector?

Answer (score 0):

You can't just leave the pending intents in the memory.. Android garbage collector automatically cleans up the activity instances accordingly...